# Integer/ int autoboxing query with generic functions in Java

Tags: java, generics, integer, int, autoboxing

Okay, so I am trying to write a generic sorting package in Java (I'm taking an algorithms course and I see it as good practice, both in the algorithmic sense and in Java as I'm very new to the language). Anyway, I figure the best way to do this is to create a `Sort` class with multiple sorting methods within, such as `insertionSort`, `mergeSort` etc. If you feel there's a better way of doing this, please let me know as a comment as I am always open to suggestions for writing cleaner and more efficient code.

As for the question:

I have the backbone structure down and want to try coding the `insertionSort` method first. However, I have tried to pass it an integer array but am getting some problems. Firstly, with generics I understand that you have to use `<Integer>` as opposed to `<int>`, but for some reason if I create an array such as `int[] arr = new int[]{..}` and pass this in to the generic it does not work. How do I fix this without using `Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{..}`? I was under the impression that the compiler would box my `int` to `Integer` automatically?

My code:

```
public class Sort<T> {
    public T[] insertionSort(T[] array) {
        // do some stuff
        return array;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] orig = new int[]{1,35,3,2,4634,2,46,7,33,56};
        Sort<Integer> sorter = new Sort<Integer>();
        sorter.insertionSort(orig);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does it mean "it does not work"? can you please give us the stack trace

Comment: I would not care about the sorting algorithm unless it is a significant part of your code. I would use `Collections.sort()` and `Arrays.sort()` instead.

Comment: @PrR3 I get a warning in my IDE telling me that it's not applicable for the type int[], but only Integer[].

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Read my first paragraph, it's a programming exercise for myself, both for Java practice and algorithms practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How do I fix this without using Integer[] arr = new Integer[]{..}?

You don't. This simply won't work.

> I was under the impression that the compiler would box my int to Integer automatically?

It will, for individual `int` to `Integer` values. But there's no conversion from `int[]` to `Integer[]`... so combined with the lack of primitive support in Java generics, a method taking a `T[]` simply *cannot* take an `int[]`.

There are third-party libraries which have conversion methods, but they will always create a *new* array, rather than creating a view onto the existing array. (It would be possible to create a `List<Integer>` which was a view onto the existing array, although obviously `add` operations would have to fail, as would `set` operations with a `null` value.)

Comment: How does the `java.utils.Arrays` package work when sorting an `int[]`?

Comment: @Keir: It has a separate method for it - it's as simple as that. I suspect each overload has a separate - possibly autogenerated - implementation. See the source for details of course.